# Uplift model with a continuous outcome?

Tags: r, machine-learning, predictive-models, python

Does anyone know any good packages (preferably in R/python) or references that are specifically about building the uplift model with a "continuous" outcome?

I've used the upliftRF from R and made it work for the binary case, but am wondering if there is a similar approach for the continuous target as well.

Comment: In case, anyone would be still interested, PyLift package for python can threat the continuous outcome.
https://github.com/wayfair/pylift

Answer (score 3):

All meta approaches for treatment effect/uplift estimation work equally for continuous and categorical outcomes, for example the two-model approach or transformed outcome approach [1].

The recent and efficient R package {grf} implements the causal forest [2] that works similar to the upliftRF, but for both continuous and categorical outcomes.

[1]Knaus, M. C., Lechner, M., & Strittmatter, A. (2019). Machine Learning Estimation of Heterogeneous Causal Effects: Empirical Monte Carlo Evidence. IZA Discussion Paper, 12039.
[2] Athey, S., Tibshirani, J., & Wager, S. (2019). Generalized random forests. The Annals of Statistics, 47(2), 1148–1178.